# How to create multiple threads inside of a for loop

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

Hi I am somewhat new to Java.

I have a method that takes in a map, and for each key value pair in the map it writes to a file.

I want to have a thread per key,value pair in the map running so that I can create multiple files at the same time. Not sure what is the proper way of doing this or how to use executor service to do get this done.

Here is a very simple example of what I'm trying to. Instead of writing all the code for writing the file Im just using system.out.println in the example:

```
public class CityWriter
{

 public static void main(String []args)
 {
    LinkedHashMap<Integer, ArrayList<City>> stateNumCitiesMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, ArrayList<City>>();

    stateNumCitiesMap  = retrieveStateCitiesMap();

    int numOfThreadsToExecuteAtATime = 10;
    
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numOfThreadsToExecuteAtATime);
    
    for(Integer key : stateNumCitiesMap.keySet()) //Could have up to 50 key,values in map
    {   
        executor.execute(writeCitiesOfStateToFile(key, StateNumCitiesMap.get(key)));
    }
    
    executor.shutdown();

 }

public LinkedHashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Cities>> writeCitiesOfStateToFile(int stateNum, List<City> citiesList) 
{
    for(City city : citiesList)
    {
        System.out.println(stateNum +" "+ city);
    }
}

}//end of class
```

My problem is that it doesn't seem like it is executing threads in parallel here. Also I don't want to run more than 10 threads at a time even though the for loop will call the executor 50 times.

please let me know what would be the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: Are the files that you are trying to write really big ? Because it might be useless to multi-thread all of that if they are small files. If they are big, you could try to use two or three threads and write the files. When one file has been written, you go to the next one with another available thread. If you want a summary on multit-treading, just look at [Tutorialpoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm)

Comment: Does this compile? There's no `this ` in a static method, and `writeCitiesOfStateToFile` isn't a valid argument for `execute () `.

Comment: Yes the files are really big and the actual code in the method before writing to the files takes a while to complete.

Comment: Sorry did not check if it compiled I made up a simple example on the spot

Comment: Hi @daniu. I want to be able to multi thread this method does it have to be Runnable and return runnable or is there another way?

Comment: Making file IO multithreaded isn't going to be very useful. You have multiple processor cores, but you have only one disk.

Comment: even if its just 5-10 more io threads it would still help me out speed this up

Comment: There's no such thing as "IO threads", that's the problem. It won't speed it up at all. No matter how many threads you have writing, they will all wait to write through to the same disk. Unless the threads are doing CPU processing (significant amounts) they'll just be trying to go through the same one door. Multithreading isn't "make everything faster" magic.

Comment: I see I wasnt aware of that. I thought it would speed things up by having 1 thread work on one file.

Comment: It would if you had every file on their own harddrive.

Comment: Why exactly do you say "it doesn't seem like it is executing threads in parallel"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, if i understood your question well, your code does exactly what you want(of course if we omit all syntax errors in your code snippet):

- It does not spawn more than 10 threads, because you have specified here `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)` how many threads you want
- All your x map entries will be assigned to executor as potential job. Then executor will run each of them in parallel with all 10 threads(but no more than 10 jobs at once)

You can try this snippet out and check that several threads are doing the job in parallel:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, List<String>> stateNumCitiesMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            stateNumCitiesMap.put(i, Collections.singletonList("ABC"));
        }

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        for (Integer key : stateNumCitiesMap.keySet()) {
            executor.execute(() -> writeCitiesOfStateToFile(key, stateNumCitiesMap.get(key)));
        }

        executor.shutdown();
    }

    public static void writeCitiesOfStateToFile(int stateNum, List<String> citiesList) {
        for (String city : citiesList) {
            System.out.println(stateNum + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }
```

In case you don't want to give a job one by one to the executor, you can pass a batch of them once.

```java
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Map<Integer, List<String>> stateNumCitiesMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            stateNumCitiesMap.put(i, Collections.singletonList("ABC"));
        }

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        List<Callable<Void>> jobs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Integer key : stateNumCitiesMap.keySet()) {
            jobs.add(() -> {
                writeCitiesOfStateToFile(key, stateNumCitiesMap.get(key));
                return null;
            });
        }
        executor.invokeAll(jobs);

        executor.shutdown();
    }

    public static void writeCitiesOfStateToFile(int stateNum, List<String> citiesList) {
        for (String city : citiesList) {
            System.out.println(stateNum + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In java you need to provide the runnable interface to any object you wish to run in a thread , you are not doing this and this is what the executor is expecting.

```
 executor.execute(() -> your function )
```

is actually

```
 executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // your code 
                }
            });
```

the method does not implement runnables , only in the run method of runnable will it be threaded

the reason is that the executor uses a kind of observer pattern and you subscribe the runnable to it , the executor then runs the run method

from java docs :

The Runnable interface should be implemented by any class whose instances are intended to be executed by a thread. The class must define a method of no arguments called run.
This interface is designed to provide a common protocol for objects that wish to execute code while they are active. For example, Runnable is implemented by class Thread. Being active simply means that a thread has been started and has not yet been stopped.

Can also make the method return a runnable itself

```
 public static Runnable writeCitiesOfStateToFile(params) {

        return  () -> System.out.println(params);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "invokeAll" method for multiple executions and even get their results (as done or not). It will use 10 thread for them even they are 50. The results will be returned when all tasks are completed. Something like below, take it as pseudo.

```
Callable<int> callableTask = (fileName) -> {
// implement write to the file
        return 0;
    };
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
     
List<Callable<int>> tasksList;
for(City city : citiesList)
{
    tasksList.add(callableTask(city.toString()));
}

executor.invokeAll(tasksList);
```

Answer (score 1):

## `Executor#execute` may be synchronous

You said:

> it doesn't seem like it is executing threads in parallel here

You did not explain the reason for that perception.

But, FYI, that may indeed be the case. You called the [`execute`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute(java.lang.Runnable)) method on your [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

```java
    for(Integer key : stateNumCitiesMap.keySet()) //Could have up to 50 key,values in map
    {   
        executor.execute(writeCitiesOfStateToFile(key, StateNumCitiesMap.get(key)));
    }
```

That [`execute`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute(java.lang.Runnable)) method is inherited from the [`Executor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) interface, the super-interface of `ExecutorService`. That interface, and its method, are documented as *maybe* running your task asynchronously. To quote the Javadoc:

> The command may execute in a new thread, in a pooled thread, or in the calling thread, at the discretion of the Executor implementation.

So you may indeed be seeing sequential non-thread synchronous execution rather than async.

From my reading of the `ExecutorService` methods `submit`, `invokeAll`, & `invokeAny`, these seem to be promising to always run asynchronously.

I do not believe such synchronous behavior is happening though, given your choice of `ExecutorService` implementation. Your call to `Executors.newFixedThreadPool` produces an object of type `ThreadPoolExecutor`. [Looking briefly at the source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/616244f43aa68543e20f1eefedd67ca8c81669e1/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java#L327) of that concrete class’ `execute` method, it appears to always work asynchronously (though I am not entirely sure).

Nevertheless, it would seem that we should *not* always assume async execution when using `Executor#execute`.